# js fetch 2 формы

Tags: javascript, fetch

Пытаюсь через js fetch отправлять данные формы на страницу обработчик. Если на первичной странице (где сам скрипт и отображается форма) находится один блок , то js fetch обрабатывает без проблем. Если уже добавить вторую форму, то срабатывает форма, которая выше по коду страницы.

```
<script>
async function SendForm(e)
{
  const form = document.getElementById('form_comment');
    // останавливает действие по умолчанию
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // отправляем POST запрос на сервер
    let response = await fetch('addpostcomment.php', {
        method: 'POST',          // метод POST
        body: new FormData(form) // в класс FormData передаем ссылку на форму
    });
    
    newCommentText = document.getElementById("newCommentText").value;
    thisUser = document.getElementById("thisUser").innerHTML;   
    thisUserComment = '<div class="media flex pb-4"><a class="inline-block mr-4" href="#"><img class="rounded-full max-w-none w-12 h-12" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/76.jpg" /></a><div class="media-body"><div><a class="inline-block text-base font-bold mr-2" href="#">'+thisUser+'</a><span class="text-slate-500">сейчас</span></div><p>'+newCommentText+'</p><div class="mt-2 flex items-center"><a class="inline-flex items-center py-2 mr-3" href="#"><span class="mr-2"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="heart"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.172 5.172a4 4 0 015.656 0L10 6.343l1.172-1.171a4 4 0 115.656 5.656L10 17.657l-6.828-6.829a4 4 0 010-5.656z" clip-rule="evenodd" /></svg></span><span class="text-base font-bold">0</span></a><button class="py-2 px-4 font-medium hover:bg-slate-50 rounded-lg">Ответить</button></div></div></div>';
    form.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', thisUserComment);
    document.getElementById("newCommentText").value ="";
};

// при щелчке на кнопку отправки формы
// отправляем форму на сервер
form.onsubmit = SendForm;
//добавление нового DIV с комментарием


</script>
```

Форма №1, которая отправляется без проблем

```
<form id="form_comment" class="pb-6">
        <div class="relative">
        <input
            class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block p-2.5 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500 pt-2 pb-2 pl-3 w-full h-11 placeholder:text-slate-600 font-light pr-20"
            type="text" name="newComment" id="newCommentText" placeholder="Добавьте комментарий" />
        <span class="flex absolute right-3 top-2/4 -mt-3 items-center">
            <svg class="mr-2" style="width: 26px; height: 26px;" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            </svg>
            <input class="hidden" type="text" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $this_post_user_id[0];?>">
            <input type="text" class="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $post_id;?>">
            <input type="submit" class="items-center bg-white text-blue-500 font-normal">
        </span>
        </div>
```

Если добавляю форму №2 ВЫШЕ формы №1 на страницу, то отправляется именно она.

```
<form action="deletepost.php" method="POST">
                  <button  data-modal-toggle="popup-modal" type="submit" name="asd" class="text-white bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-red-300 dark:focus:ring-red-800 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2.5 text-center mr-2">
                    Да, я уверен
                </button>
                <input class="hidden" type="text" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $this_post_user_id[0];?>">
                <input type="text" class="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $post_id;?>">
                <form>
```

добавление в скрипт прямого обращения к форме `const form = document.getElementById('form_comment');` не помогает

как привязать отправку через fetch к конкретной форме?

Answer (score 0):

На странице одновременно может быть только одна форма с уникальным id. По уникальному id вы обращаетесь только к первой форме. Добавьте второй форме другой id, например form_comment_1, и обращатесь к ней отдельно

```
const form = document.getElementById('form_comment_1');
```